# NullPointerException when trying to test using JUnit5

Tags: java, junit

So I am trying to test this code:

```
@Test
public void faarFalse() throws IOException {
    String filStiTilArrangementer = "src/main/java/gruppeeksamen/arrangementer.csv";
    String filStiTilLoggetInn = "../../View/loggetInn.fxml";

    ObservableList listeFor = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    dataHandler.hentDataHele(filStiTilArrangementer, listeFor);

    navnPaaArrangement = "Test arrangement";
    datoPaaArrangement = "2020-10-10";
    typeIdrettPaaArrangement = "Ski";
    leggTilArrangementController.leggeTilArrangementet(navnPaaArrangement, datoPaaArrangement, typeIdrettPaaArrangement, filStiTilArrangementer, filStiTilLoggetInn); //Line 148 ref. error message

    ObservableList listeEtter = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    dataHandler.hentDataHele(filStiTilArrangementer, listeEtter);
    assertTrue(listeFor.size() < listeEtter.size());

    //fjernet linjen som er lagt til
    RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(filStiTilArrangementer, "rw");
    long length = f.length() - 1;
    byte b;
    do {
        length -= 1;
        f.seek(length);
        b = f.readByte();
    } while(b != 10);
    f.setLength(length+1);
    f.close();
}
```

which is testing this code:

```
public class LeggTilArrangementController {

@FXML
private Button btnGaaTilbake;

public void leggeTilArrangementet(String arrangement, String dato, String idrett, String filstienTilArrangementene, String filstienTilLoggetInn) {
    //sjekker om alle "forhåndsregler" er gjort for å kunne legge til et arrangement
    if (sjekkOmAlleInputErFyltUt(arrangement, dato, idrett) && sjekkOmdagensDatoErMindreEnnDatePicker(dato) && arrangementPaaSammeDatoIkkeFinnes(arrangement, dato.replace("-","."), idrett)){
        //lager en ny linje med navnet på arrangementet, antall utøvere (som fra start skal være 0), utøvere (som fra start skal være tom), datoen (åååå.mm.dd), type idrett
        String nyttArrangement = arrangement + ";0"/*antall utøvere*/ + ";" /*utøvere*/ + ";" + dato.replace("-",".") + ";" + idrett + "\n";
        //prøver å legge til arrangementet på sisten av arrangementer.csv
        try {
            FileWriter filenSomSkalSkrivesTil = new FileWriter(filstienTilArrangementene, true);
            filenSomSkalSkrivesTil.append(nyttArrangement);
            filenSomSkalSkrivesTil.flush();
            filenSomSkalSkrivesTil.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //lukker nåværende vindu
        goBack(filstienTilLoggetInn); //Line 76 ref. error message
    } else {
        MainJavaFX.visAlertFeilmelding("Mangler arrangement, dato eller idrett","Må fylle inn en av delene");
    }
}


private void goBack(String filstienTilLoggetInn) {
    Stage stage = (Stage) btnGaaTilbake.getScene().getWindow(); //Line 50 ref. error message
    stage.close();
    DataHandler.sendTilNyScene(filstienTilLoggetInn, "Arrengementer", 500, 500);
}
}
```

The test is supposed to test if a new line has been wrote to a CSV-file, but when i try to run the test, all I get is this message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at gruppeeksamen.Controller.LeggTilArrangementController.goBack(LeggTilArrangementController.java:50)
at gruppeeksamen.Controller.LeggTilArrangementController.leggeTilArrangementet(LeggTilArrangementController.java:76)
at gruppeeksamen.Controller.LeggTilArrangementControllerTest.faarFalse(LeggTilArrangementControllerTest.java:148)
```

Anyone know why I get this error message? 
**PS:** When i delete/comment out line 76 ref. error message, the test works all fine, but then the program won't work.

Comment: Could you add where you declare/initialize the "btnGaaTilbake" variable please?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code and line that you have highlighted it could be due to one of two reasons:

```
btnGaaTilbake.getScene()
```

Either `btnGaaTilbake` is null or method `getScene()` is retuning null. Kindly check both the variables are returning correct values.